# Can I set NavigateUrl from a Static class property?

Tags: asp.net

I have the following code in my page file:

```
<td style=" text-align:center">
    <asp:HyperLink 
        ID="HyperLink1" 
        Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Name") %>' 
        runat="server" 
        NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format(Link_EditResume, DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Id")) %>'> 
    </asp:HyperLink>
</td>
```

The variable Link_EditResume is a string declared in the code-behind for the page and defined as

```
public partial class ProspectSummary : BasePage
{
    protected string Link_EditResume = Links.EditResume;
    ...
```

where Links is a static class and EditResume is a property of that class.  Why does this work and referencing Links.EditResume directly in the aspx file not work?  Is there a way to reference this directly in the aspx?

Thanks.

Comment: In what sense did it not work? Did you get an error, or unexpected behaviour, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you did not import the namespace that `Links` lives in into your ASPX page.

Your ASPX page should start with an [Import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb44kack.aspx) directive as so:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="Steves.Namespace.Containing.LinksConstants" %>

<td style=" text-align:center">
    <asp:HyperLink 
        NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format(Links.EditResume, DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Id")) %>'> 
    </asp:HyperLink>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks. Should have been obvious but I was assuming I wouldn't need this since the static class was in the App_Code folder for the website and the namespace was "MyWebsite".